# tablet size qualifiers not being used

Tags: android

I am creating an app for tablets only (`large` and `xlarge` devices). I have three layouts which I am trying to use.

1. One set is for large devices of 800x480 resolutions (`layout` folder).
2. One set is for xlarge devices of minimum width of 1280px (`layout-w1280dp`)
3. One set is for xlarge devices who are less than 1280px (`layout-w1024dp` - there are no xlarge devices < 1024px wide)

So I've done the above but it is not working. My 1280x800 tablet is displaying layouts from the `layout` folder. I'm also getting this error in console but I cannot understand why I am getting it

`w1024dp/w1280dp is not a best match for any device .. displaying it with Displaying it with 'Locale Language ___Region __, sw800dp, w1280dp, h800dp....xyz`

Comment: Oh. I have found out you need to be running android 3.2+ for these qualifiers to have an effect. Surely not many tablets are running 3.2+, is there another way I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, these qualifiers are not around until 3.2.  You can still use, them, but only >= 3.2 will use them.

For <3.2 devices, within XML, you'll have to make due with the size/density.  Your directories could be very specific, such as: layout-small-ldpi, layout-small-mdpi, layout-small-hdpi, layout-small-xhdpi, layout-normal-ldpi, layout-normal-mdpi, layout-normal-hdpi, etc.

Or they can just be by screen size (layout-small, layout-normal...) or just by dpi (layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi...)

If you want to get even more fine grained than the super-specificity of layout-small-ldpi, layout-small-mdpi etc., you can make calls to the DisplayMetrics class in your code, and tune things even further.  Something which is less necessary on >= 3.2 devices.